# Alfresco 4 Community Edition IMAP Integration

Tags: integration, imap, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco community edition 4.0.d

Is it possible for me to drag and drop emails from OutLook or any other mail client to Alfresco Share

Since Share is a http application

is that reason i am not able to DND from an email client to Alfresco Share.

please help me on this - i did Google for this i found only for 3.x version imap integration not found any help full information for 4.x versions.

Thanks in Advance
Devendar

Answer (score 2):

IMAP is documented as part of Alfresco's official documentation. Here is a decent starting point for IMAP on Alfresco 4:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/imap-intro.html

Unless otherwise stated, all documentation on docs.alfresco.com is applicable to both Enterprise Edition and Community Edition.